# MediaRecorder Start Failed

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I am getting this error when running start() for mediarecorder.
Following is the my code. What is the wrong with my cose?
Code:

```
public class RecordVideoActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private boolean isRecording = false;
    private Button captureButton;
    private Button goodButton;
    private Button badButton;
    Thread thread;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
    ArrayList<TrimPoint> mTrimPoints; 
    Timer mTimer;
    double currentTime=0;
    static String filepath;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recordvideo);
        loadGUI();
        mTimer = new Timer();

        mTrimPoints = new ArrayList<TrimPoint>();
        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);
    }

    private void loadGUI() {
        captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        goodButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_good);
        goodButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        badButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_bad);
        badButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_capture:
            captureButtonHandler();
            break;
        case R.id.button_bad:
            badButtonHandler();
            break;
        case R.id.button_good:
            goodButtonHandler();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    private void goodButtonHandler() {
        TrimPoint mTrimPoint = new TrimPoint(true,currentTime);
        mTrimPoints.add(mTrimPoint);
    }

    private void badButtonHandler() {
        TrimPoint mTrimPoint = new TrimPoint(false,currentTime);
        mTrimPoints.add(mTrimPoint);
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_MONO);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);

        if(thread != null){
            thread = null;
        }
        thread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //while(true) {
                        int time = 5000;
                        Log.d("HFI","Time: "+time);
                        sleep(time);
                        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                        params.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NONE);
                        mCamera.setParameters(params);
                    //}
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        thread.start();
    }

    private void captureButtonHandler() {
        if (isRecording) {
            // stop recording and release camera
            mMediaRecorder.stop(); // stop the recording
            mTimer.cancel();
            releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
            mCamera.lock(); // take camera access back from MediaRecorder

            // inform the user that recording has stopped
            captureButton.setText("Capture");
            mCamera.startPreview();
            isRecording = false;

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); //I encourage using this instead of specifying the string "android.intent.action.VIEW"
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(filepath), "video/mp4");
            startActivity(intent);  

        } else {
            // initialize video camera
            if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
                // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is
                // prepared,
                // now you can start recording

                mMediaRecorder.start();

                // inform the user that recording has started
                captureButton.setText("Stop");
                isRecording = true;

                mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        currentTime = currentTime+1;
                    }
                }, 1000,1000);
            } else {
                // prepare didn't work, release the camera
                releaseMediaRecorder();
                // inform user
            }
        }
    }

    private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            //start Asyntask here. progress show/hide should be done in asynctaswk itself.
        }
    };


    /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
    public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
            if (c != null) {
                Camera.Parameters params = c.getParameters();
                c.setParameters(params);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Camera did not open: " + e.toString());
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    private boolean prepareVideoRecorder() {

        if(mMediaRecorder == null){
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        }else{
            Log.d(Constants.TAG,"MediaRecoder is Not Null");
        }
        // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.unlock();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

        // Step 2: Set sources
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
        mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));

        // Step 4: Set output file
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());

        // Step 5: Set the preview output
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

        // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),"HFVideos");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        filepath = mediaFile.toString();
        Log.d(Constants.TAG,"Path: "+filepath);
        return mediaFile;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseMediaRecorder(); // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it
                                // first
        releaseCamera(); // release the camera immediately on pause event
    }

    private void releaseMediaRecorder() {
        if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
            mMediaRecorder.reset(); // clear recorder configuration
            mMediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mMediaRecorder = null;
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.lock(); // lock camera for later use
        }
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            isRecording = false;
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.release(); // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Logcat:

```
03-27 10:00:17.849: I/MediaRecorderJNI(2736): prepare: surface=0x26c898 (identity=147)
03-27 10:00:17.869: E/MediaRecorder(2736): start failed: -19
03-27 10:00:17.869: D/AndroidRuntime(2736): Shutting down VM
03-27 10:00:17.869: W/dalvikvm(2736): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a92930)
03-27 10:00:17.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2736): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 10:00:17.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2736): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
03-27 10:00:17.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2736):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
03-27 10:00:17.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2736):     at uk.org.humanfocus.hfi.RecordVideoActivity.captureButtonHandler(RecordVideoActivity.java:151)
03-27 10:00:17.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2736):     at uk.org.humanfocus.hfi.RecordVideoActivity.onClick(RecordVideoActivity.java:77)
03-27 10:00:17.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2736):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
03-27 10:00:17.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2736):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17344)
03-27 10:00:17.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2736):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-27 10:00:17.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2736):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-27 10:00:17.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2736):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-27 10:00:17.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2736):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5191)
03-27 10:00:17.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2736):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 10:00:17.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2736):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-27 10:00:17.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2736):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
03-27 10:00:17.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2736):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
03-27 10:00:17.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2736):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Deleted my answer-  I made a mistake, that was for a player not a recorder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved. The Problem was due to `CyanogenMod` which I am using in My Android Device.

Got Solution while searching `thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a92930)`